# How can I load two grunt tasks with the same name?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Im using yeoman for a project.

Basically it's working fine, but during the build process I want to move my images folder to somewhere else.

So I loaded the `grunt-contrib-copy` task which would let me do that. But unfortunately this conflicts with the yeoman built-in copy task.

Is there any way to alias the `grunt-contrib-copy` in my `Gruntfile.js` so I can use both of them?

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

//Here I need to use "copy" again but not referencing the yeoman task but the grunt-contrib-copy task.
grunt.registerTask('build','intro clean coffee compass mkdirs concat css min replace copy time');
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[grunt.renameTask()](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.renametask) will probably help you here. Try this:

```js
// temporarily rename yeoman's copy task
grunt.renameTask('copy', 'yeomanCopy');
// load 'copy' from grunt-contrib-copy
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
// rename it to something other than 'copy'
grunt.renameTask('copy', 'myCopy');
// rename yeoman's task back to its original name so nothing breaks
grunt.renameTask('yeomanCopy', 'copy');

// now use 'myCopy' for your purposes
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Though I have the problem that some tasks check if a certain task has been executed before and don't know about their renaming :-/

Comment: But you are renaming the existing yeoman's task back right away, aren't you?

Comment: Oops, I stopped at renaming the original task, of course you are right. Thank you Dmitry!